# button handler and awaitMessageComponent

Tags: javascript, node.js, button, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a button that confirms an action within a command, but I can't because my button handler prevents it. It understands that there is no function programmed for that button and rejects any action made there. Is there a way to resolve it?

**Command**

```
const response = await interaction.reply({
      embeds: [embed],
      components: [actionRow],
      ephemeral: true,
    });

    const collector = (i) => i.user.id === interaction.user.id;

    try {
      const confirmation = await response.awaitMessageComponent({
        filter: collector,
        time: 60000,
      });

      if (confirmation.customId === "channel_confirm") {
        await confirmation.update({
          content: `Mensagem enviada!`,
          components: [],
          embeds: [],
        });
      }
      if (confirmation.customId === "channel_cancelar") {
        await confirmation.update({
          content: `Ação cancelada.`,
          components: [],
          embeds: [],
        });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      await interaction.editReply({
        content: `Não recebi nenhuma confirmação em 1 minutos, acho que vou cancelar...`,
        components: [],
        embeds: [],
      });
    }
```

**Button handler**

```
if (interaction.isButton()) {
    const { buttons } = client;
    const { customId } = interaction;
    const button = buttons.get(customId);
    if (!button)
      return interaction.reply({
        content: `Esse botão ainda não possui nenhuma função.`,
        ephemeral: true,
      });
    try {
      await button.execute(client, interaction);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one way by which I can think you can resolve the issue. You can prefix in the ***[`customId`](https://discordjs.guide/message-components/buttons.html#building-buttons)*** of your buttons to differentiate between global buttons (handled by the button handler) and local buttons (specific to certain commands) post which in your button handler, you can check for the prefix before processing the button interactions.

1. Update your command to include the prefix for the button `customId`.

   ```js
   // In your command, when creating the buttons
   const confirmButton = new MessageButton()
   .setCustomId("local_channel_confirm") // <--- Notice this
   .setLabel("Confirm")
   .setStyle("SUCCESS");

   const cancelButton = new MessageButton()
   .setCustomId("local_channel_cancelar")
   .setLabel("Cancelar")
   .setStyle("DANGER");

   const actionRow = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(confirmButton, cancelButton);
   ```
2. Update the button handler to check if the customId starts with the local prefix. If it does, ignore the interaction.

   ```js
   if (interaction.isButton()) {
     const { buttons } = client;
     const { customId } = interaction;

     // Ignore local buttons
    if (customId.startsWith("local_")) {
       // Defer the reply for local buttons
      return interaction.deferUpdate(); // <--- Edited here
    }

    const button = buttons.get(customId);
    if (!button)
       return interaction.reply({
         content: `Esse botão ainda não possui nenhuma função.`,
         ephemeral: true,
      });
    try {
      await button.execute(client, interaction);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
   }
   ```

Comment: I did this, but when I click on the button with the customId "local_" it shows that the interaction fails.

Comment: @Amees I have updated my answer. Give it a try. Instead of just returning I deffered the reply.